# Regex Matching, Java. Match & Extract

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I know this has been asked a million times, but I can't get it to work.
I'm filtering strings from a game's web API (http://pathofexile.com/api/public-stash-tabs -- Careful, ~5MB of data will retrieve from GET), trying to find which type of attribute I'm looking at, because I later need to replace it. (I'm looking at the "explicitMods" array within each of the Item objects, and identifying which type of modifier it is.)

My goal is to first identify which type of modifier I am dealing with, and then use `String.replaceAll` to substitute the proper strings with `##` so that I can later replace `##` with actual values and search. I would be storing the values, or ranges, so that I can later identify what matches. `String.replaceAll` not included here, because that bit works just fine.

This is my test class. All tests fail. I did test each pattern on regex101.com, to be sure but they only have javascript, php, python, and golang testers. Each method comment has a link to the test I made on regex101.

```
package arbitrary.package.name;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class RegexTests {

  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegexTests.class);

  @Test
  public void testIntegers() {
    // https://regex101.com/r/PVfYGX/1
    assertTrue(compileAndMatch("/.*(.\\d+).+(.\\d+).*/", "Adds 80 to 115 Physical Damage"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testIntegersWithRanges() {
    // https://regex101.com/r/u3UQqM/1
    assertTrue(compileAndMatch("/.*(\\d+-\\d+).*(\\d+-\\d+).*/", "Adds (4-5) to (8-9) Physical Damage"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testDecimals() {
    // https://regex101.com/r/CpaV1y/1
    assertTrue(compileAndMatch("/.*(\\d+.?\\d+).*/", "0.2% of Elemental Damage Leeched as Life"));
  }

  private boolean compileAndMatch(String regex, String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    log.info("{} {} \"{}\"", regex, matcher.matches() ? "matches" : "does not match", text);
    return pattern.matcher(text).matches();
  }
}
```

Sample stacktrace (all are the same):

```
2017-02-20 20:35:44.876 [main] INFO  arbitrary.package.name.RegexTests - /.*(\d+.?\d+).*(\d+.?\d+).*/ does not match "Adds (4-5) to (8-9) Physical Damage" 

java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at arbitrary.package.name.RegexTests.testIntegersWithRanges(RegexTests.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
".*(\\d+-\\d+).*(\\d+-\\d+).*"
```

Java

```
String regex = ".*(\\d+-\\d+).*(\\d+-\\d+).*";
String text = "Adds (4-5) to (8-9) Physical Damage";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Comment: Thanks so much. JavaScript mind leaking into Java, silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your should remove the `/` in the start and end position

Comment: Thanks Kerwin, that's correct. I wrote in the other guy's response as the answer because he replied before you.